# Can you dynamically switch a Serverless function authorizer based on your stage?

Tags: serverless-framework

The concept is fairly straightforward: I want to be able to use a different authorizer for functions when testing locally (with `serverless-offline`) vs. when the API is deployed:

```
functionName:
    handler: handler.functionName
    events:
    - http:
        path: my/function
        method: get
        authorizer:
            name: localAuthorizer
            # arn: arn:aws:lambda:rest:goes:here
```

Is there any way to dynamically switch between that `localAuthorizer` and a full `arn` to my remote authorizer based on the stage I'm running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables/

Should be able to create an environment variable so you can swap between two cloud formation references depending on the setting.

Comment: Got this working great using a few of the SLS variable features: I created a set of JS config files named `[stage]-config.js` – so that the stage-specific config file can be loaded dynamically – that exports an object with various config settings; loaded that object into my `serverless.yaml` file's `custom` variables definition – `custom: ${file(../../config/${opt:stage}-config.js)}`; and then used those configuration values throughout the yaml file – e.g. `${self:custom.variableName}`.